# Modifying Individual Bytes in Rust

Tags: rust

In C, if I want to modify the most significant byte of an integer, I can do it in two different ways:

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    uint32_t i1 = 0xDDDDDDDD;
    printf("i1 original: 0x%X\n", i1);
    uint32_t i1msb = 0xAA000000;
    uint32_t i1_mask = 0x00FFFFFF;
    uint32_t i1msb_mask = 0xFF000000;
    i1 = (i1 & i1_mask) | (i1msb & i1msb_mask);
    printf("i1 modified: 0x%X\n", i1);

    uint32_t i2 = 0xDDDDDDDD;
    printf("i2 original: 0x%X\n", i2);
    uint32_t *i2ptr = &i2;
    char *c2ptr = (char *) i2ptr;
    c2ptr += 3;
    *c2ptr = 0xAA;
    printf("i2 modified: 0x%X\n", i2);
}
```

```
i1 original: 0xDDDDDDDD
i1 modified: 0xAADDDDDD
i2 original: 0xDDDDDDDD
i2 modified: 0xAADDDDDD
```

The masking approach works in both C and Rust, but I don't have not found any way to do the direct byte manipulation approach in (safe) Rust. Although it has some endianness issues that masking does not, I think these can all be resolved at compile time to provide a safe, cross-platform interface, so why is direct byte manipulation not allowed in safe Rust? Or if it is, please correct me as I have been unable to find a function for it - I am thinking something like

```rust
fn change_byte(i: &u32, byte_num: usize, new_val: u8) -> Result<(), ErrorType> { ... }
```

which checks that byte_num is within range before performing the operation, and in which byte_num always goes from least significant byte to most significant.

Answer (score 0):

Rust doesn't have a function to modify bytes directly. It does, however, have methods to convert integers to byte arrays, and byte arrays to integers.  For example, one might write

```rust
fn set_low_byte(number:u32, byte:u8)->u32{
  let mut arr = number.to_be_bytes();
  arr[3] = byte;
  u32::from_be_bytes(arr)
}
```

There are also methods for little and native endian byte order. The bitmask approach is also perfectly doable, and the pointer stuff will also work if you don't mind `unsafe`.

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=%0A%0Afn%20main()%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20num%20%3D%200xDDDDDDDD%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20byte%20%3D%200xAA%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20new_num%20%3D%20set_low_byte(num%2Cbyte)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20assert_eq!(new_num%2C0xDDDDDDAA)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20set_low_byte(number%3Au32%2C%20byte%3Au8)-%3Eu32%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20arr%20%3D%20number.to_be_bytes()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20arr%5B3%5D%20%3D%20byte%3B%0A%20%20%20%20u32%3A%3Afrom_be_bytes(arr)%0A%7D)